# SC.Widget.Events.FINISH only firing once with HTML5 Embed Widget

Tags: javascript, html, widget, bind, soundcloud

I successfully bound SC.Widget.Events.FINISH to my widget, but it won't run more than once. I read that this issue was fixed it 2013, but it's still present. (I recall this code working last year, or the year before that, so it must be a new iteration of the same bug.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<audio src="intro.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<iframe onload="javascript:LoadWidget()" id="lure" width="100%" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/135934116&amp;enable_api=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true">
</iframe>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("Hey!")
Boom = "http://162.13.25.174/urw14a2kb"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeElement   = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeElementID = iframeElement.id;
var widget1         = SC.Widget(iframeElement)
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("It is running. Kinda.")
var iframeElement   = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var iframeElementID = iframeElement.id;
var widget1         = SC.Widget(iframeElement[0])
//alert("It's on.")
//var player = SC.getPlayer('102641127')
console.log("Window has " + Object.keys(window).length)
console.log("window's Object is " + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window))
DatMap = new window.Map()
//alert(DatMap)
console.log("SC has " + Object.keys(window.SC).length)
console.log("SC is " + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.SC))
console.log("SC.Widget() has " +         Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.SC.Widget("lure")))
//setTimeout(LoadWidget, 1000)
function GotIt(response) {
    //alert("GotIt is now running")
    //alert(response)
    i = 0
    for(key in response) {
        i = i + 1
    }
    //alert(i)
    i = i - 1
    //playNextTrack()
    MyWidget.play()
    //alert(Object.keys(MyWidget).length)
    //alert("Properties of MyWidget: " +     Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyWidget))
    MyWidget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, playNextTrack())

}
function reBind() {
    MyWidget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, playNextTrack())
}
function playNextTrack() {
    console.log(alert("playNextTrack fired."))
    MyWidget.skip(Math.floor((Math.random() * i) + 0));
    MyWidget.bind(C.Widget.Events.PLAY, reBind())
}
function LoadWidget() {
    MyWidget = window.SC.Widget("lure");
    //alert(Object.keys(MyWidget.getSounds(GotIt)).length)
    GetSounds = Object.keys(MyWidget.getSounds(GotIt)).length
}
//tracks = window.SC.Widget('/user/183/tracks')
//alert(window.SC.get(iframeElementID))
//alert('Latest track: ' + tracks[0].title);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now. Please try again and let us know if there is still a problem!